# Wordpress subpages throwing 404 after restoring

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, virtualhost, web-hosting

I am a newbie to wordpress though I have programming background. Recently I moved a wordpress website from justhost shared server to a
linode vps server (Ubuntu OS). I did following steps to achieve it

1. Set up apache2 server on vps
2. Set up virtualhost on vps
3. Created a directory under /var/www/ftpadmin/www/
   Note. ftpadmin was created to restrict ftp access to files under that folder. I could make work static html and php websites after doing so.
4. Took backup of database and wp-content folder from justhost server of respective wordpress website.
5. Now on vps, at specified location above, first I download latest version of wordpress and unzipped the files.
6. Created database of same name at mysql and then imported original to the same database.
7. replaced new wp-content folder with the one from original one.
8. I was following instructions on https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-multiple-wordpress-sites-on-a-single-ubuntu-vps.
9. restarted apache server. Now I could access the home page.
10. I corrected the database values for wordpress url and site address url to new one at older location and reloaded database which helped me access dashboard and login pages also.
11. I created a .htaccess file like mentioned in http://ahsan.vimmaniac.com/blog/enabling-wordpress-permalinks-on-ubuntu/.
12. I also changed "AllowOveride" under both section in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ as

    ```
    <Directory />
     Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride all
    </Directory>

     <Directory /var/www/ftpadmin/www/domainname>
     RewriteEngine On
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride FileInfo
     Order allow,deny
     allow from all
     </Directory>
    ```
13. restarted service apache once again.
14. One final point, I am using a custom template and so I have a header.php and header-sub.php file for homepage and navigation.
15. Now here is the problem. When I click on any submenu I get "Internal Server Error".
16. If I remove .htaccess and reload apache server. Now I get 404 error while clicking on and submenu.

Any help is highly appreciated? I looked at various sites to collate these many steps and execute. I have no Idea what I should do to correct this situation. But when I go dashboard -> All pages, I can find all pages existing there with contents.

Thanks in Advance
Fayaz

**EDIT**
Added `.htaccess` file from comment:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /wordpress/ (wordpress replaced with my domainname, bottom also) 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Post your htaccess file

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteBase /wordpress/ (wordpress replaced with my domainname, bottom also)
       RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

Comment: Hi Jon, sorry for pasting this away, I tried indenting but its not happening!

Comment: my permlink is  set to Post name

Comment: Hi I got it fixed, just replaced RewriteBase /wordpress/ as "RewriteBase /" and RewriteRule ./wordpress/index.php [L} as "RewriteRule . /index.php [L]". Thanks you.

Comment: If you fixed it you can answer your own question, that way it's easy to see that this issue is solved. You might want to read up on the [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page for some hints.

Answer (score 3):

I got the above problem fixed by just replacing
       RewriteBase /wordpress/ as "RewriteBase /" 
       and 
       RewriteRule ./wordpress/index.php [L} as "RewriteRule . /index.php [L]". 
in .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteBase / 
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally fixed this errow after browsing for a couple of hours and trying many options.

In this block in your Apache httpd.conf file, (located in my CentOS instance at $ sudo vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf)

```
#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
    AllowOverride None
```

change AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All.

Src: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/secondary-or-child-pages-returning-a-404-error-after-wp-34-update#post-3830892

Comment: In my case the file was etc/apache2/apache.conf, line number 173, right under <Directory /var/www/> rule